# How do I put an image behind a button?

Tags: html, css

So I made [this mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaD9F.jpg) and I'm trying to get the stripes behind my buttons. I've tried using borders-image, background-image, borders with linear gradient on added divs/buttons but none worked

https://jsfiddle.net/hoyhym/txsgcx5b/ this is my latest try, the border becomes a thick black border instead of the image, which does show in the .headerbutton but is too wide

```
<div class="headerbutton">
   <a href="#" class="button">Ontdek ons programma</a>
</div>

.headerbutton {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  //border: 10px solid black;
  //border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/dCwAQsB.png) 30 repeat;
}

.button {
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: .9rem .9rem .7rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/dCwAQsB.png) 30 repeat;
}
```

Comment: @Johannes yea, just edited

Comment: If you want stripes behind your button, you should use some `background-color` and a `background-image` (or `background: url()`)

Comment: @RenevanderLende https://jsfiddle.net/hoyhym/buesaL78/ , I made a new wrapper div and it would come out like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better way to achieve this is by using pseudo element `:after`.

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txsgcx5b/13/)

```
.button:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   top:5px;
   left:5px;
   background: url(http://i.imgur.com/dCwAQsB.png) repeat;
   z-index:-1;
 }
```

But if you insist on using border you need `background-clip:padding-box;` to prevent the background color from coloring the border itself.

Comment: yeah the ::after works better since the lines don't break in the corner, thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, with a bit of fiddling you will get: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txsgcx5b/12/)

```css
.headerbutton {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
 }

.button {
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: white;
  padding: .9rem .9rem .7rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
  border-image-source: url(http://i.imgur.com/dCwAQsB.png);
  border-image-repeat: repeat;
  border-image-width: 10px; /* thickness of the border */
  border-image-slice:  0 10 10 0; /* what slices are being used?*/
  border-image-outset: 0 10px 10px 0; /* how many pixels wide */
}
```

```html
<div class="headerbutton">
   <a href="#" class="button">Ontdek ons programma</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah but the problem with that is that I still want the black background-color like here - https://imgur.com/pmvd0TM

Comment: Ok, I misinterpreted your Q. Hold on, i'll change a few things

Comment: Looking at right and bottom offset, your border image does not entirely fit [http://border-image.com]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
.Button:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width: 30%;
    height:30%;
    top:5px;
    margin-left: 840px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/dCwAQsB.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 350px 250px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32280690)